# Read-only for the SE Application

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, read-only

I found a read-only problem on the SE app. I cannot comment because it is supposedly on read-only mode. How do I disable read-only on the SE app?

Comment: The android app has the same problem. The entire site was in read only mode until recently, probably related

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, when this problem occurred, the site was under read-only mode. This is expected behavior.

Comment: May be worth taking another look at the message displayed to see if it could be more clear that "it's not just you"?